# TabControl with Regions PRISM

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, prism, tabcontrol, prism-4

I am creating a shell. `XAML` which houses only a `TabControl`. I am trying to create new tabs on a button click event. With the code that I have written till now I am able to create new tabs on a button click event but the content of the Tab (a region) is only shown on the FIRST Tab and the  new tabs that are created are empty. I.e. I am not able to show the same content (the region) in the newly created tabs...

**Shell.XAML**

```
<TabControl Name="MyTabs" 
            Prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionConstants.MainRegion}">
</TabControl>
```

`UserControl` that I wish to add to tabs:

**MainControls.XAML**

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 

        <Grid x:Name="LeftGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionConstants.InputRegion}">

        <GridSplitter>
        <Grid x:Name="RightGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionConstants.OutputRegion}">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Function to Add Tab**

```
private void New_Tab(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TabItem tab = new TabItem();
    tab.Header = "New Tab";
    tab.Content = new MainControls();
    MyTabs.Items.Add(tab);
}
```

**Module for Registering MainRegion**

```
class CollaboratedModule :IModule
{
    private IUnityContainer container = default(IUnityContainer);
    private IRegionManager regionManager = default(IRegionManager);

    public CollaboratedModule(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        if (this.container != default(IUnityContainer) &&
            this.regionManager != default(IRegionManager))
        {
            var IntergratedView = this.container.Resolve<MainControls>();

            this.regionManager.AddToRegion(RegionConstants.MainRegion, IntergratedView);
            this.regionManager.Regions[RegionConstants.MainRegion].Activate(IntergratedView);
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly i have created a Module for registering `InputRegion` and the `OutputRegion`. Can anyone let me know where is the issue in this code and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

just try this way

```
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionConstants.MainRegion, () => IntergratedView);
```